# android eclipse setOnClickListener

Tags: android, eclipse, tabactivity

I want to set `OnClickListener` on my `button3`.

It's an activity in the second tab in `TabHost`.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;    

public class tab_act extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_tab);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

XML:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_search"
    android:drawablePadding="15dip"
    android:text="Найти совпадения" />
```

And I get an err:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View
>   is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

in this line:

> ```
> findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've imported the wrong `OnClickListener` - it should be

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

instead of `import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;`. Also you are setting `OnClickListener` for button with id `button1` while xml you provided declares button with id `button3`

**edit** It's better to implicitly specify it like so:

```
findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
...
});
```

to prevent such errors from happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `findViewById(R.id.button1)` and you should be doing `findViewById(R.id.button3)`

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: if you imported more than one method from 2 different places (for example you imported and use in the same activity both `android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and `android.view.View.OnClickListener`) you can't use shortcuts for both times when calling the `OnClickListener`, and you will somethimes have to call specificaly like so:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```